# Protection and charging circuit for LIR2032 or ML2032 battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, low-power, protection, battery-chemistry

I am designing a tiny device with very low power consumption. The device needs a rechargeable battery which should be charged from USB.

I have found LIR2032 and ML2032 batteries that can provide enough current to power the device. As I understand these two use different chemistry, so need different charging algorithm. Can one circuit support both LIR2032 and ML2032 without external switch? What protection and charging do each of the batteries require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have completely different chemistries so they have completely different charging voltages and profiles. ML is lithium manganese dioxide rechargeable and LIR seems to be standard lithium ion compatible.

So no, you can't make an universal charger for both without telling the charging circuitry which type of battery you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate on charging and protection circuits for both chemistries?

Comment: Just open the datasheets of both batteries. The other one is just standard li-ion. There is no reason for me to write a battery chemistry book for you, you can read existing battery chemistry books that already exist.